# Cual es la forma correcta de asignar un mismo valor a varias variables

Tags: javascript

El siguiente código produce el mismo resultado en ambas opciones (**Chrome & Firefox**).

```js
// opción corta
var a = b = c = d = e = 1;
console.log(a,b,c,d,e)

// opción larga
var a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d = 1, e = 1;
console.log(a,b,c,d,e)
```

Quizás la pregunta para algunos parece obvia o tonta, pero ¿cuál de estas dos opciones es la correcta o debo usar y por qué?

Comment: "The Single Var Pattern" es el tema a profundizar, tiene muchos pros y algunos contras. Pero por ahí puede iniciar.

Answer (score 3):

Esta es la forma mas corta aceptada por 'use strict', por que de resto no hay mas xd, si, se que es exactamente igual que la tuya, pero sin espacios es mas corto y ademas se usa `let` que dependiendo donde vaya a ir tu variable es mejor, ya que no contamina el scope global, en cambio `var` si lo hace:

```js
//Opcion larga
'use strict';
let a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1,e=1;
console.log(a,b,c,d,e)
```

Entre esas dos opciones que diste realmente no hay mas por poner, y destructuring no permite usar un solo valor para definir varios espacios.

No necesariamente es la `'opcion correcta'` eso es mas bien un criterio del programador, pero si la segura, cuando pones 'use strict' le estas diciendo a javascript que use el modo estricto, y podemos ver lo siguiente:

```js
// opción corta
'use strict';
let a = b = c = d = e = 1;
console.log(a,b,c,d,e)
```

Ahora lo que repentinamente sin usar el modo estricto iba bien, ya no va bien.

Conclusión:

Es mejor la segunda opción aunque sea mas larga, ya que funciona tanto en modo estricto como sin el. Ademas no existen mas formas de declarar un solo valor para varias variables en javascript.